# Differential equations dy dx last resort

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation?

It is not homogenous, or linear first order, so what can I do?

$(x+2y+7)~dy=(x+2y-1)~dx$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Set $u=x+2y-1$ and so $du=dx+2dy$ and so $$(u+8)\left(\frac{du-dx}{2}\right)=udx$$

Comment: Great hint, Babak!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. I t was soooooo simple.

Comment: ;-) Glad to see you before my heading to bed! I'll sleep better now!

Comment: Me too Amy, I know, I should wait till you be back here. I am working on relations in a semigroup right now. They don't obey me Amy. I am so angry of these blind creatures.

Comment: I love your descriptions! Keep at it...don't let those nasty creatures get the best of you ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Have a look at my poor deleted answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/374122/8581