# How does my Beltrami-Klein model look?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

[image: Scan]

Did I sketch the picture right based off of the specific instructions given in the problem?

Answer (score 4):

See this version instead. I added 3 other models here to find out the deference between them better. The Poincare's model shows the divergent lines better.

[image]

Comment: Not any more! 3rd Vote to undelete ;-) Beautiful!

Comment: Hello, dear friend! Good to see you too! It seems a bit slow today.

Comment: heheheh...I wonder if sometimes if I suffer the same...maybe we can both suffer with dementia together!

Comment: @BabakS.: Beuatiful graphics + 1

Comment: nice illustration